# PHP HTTP Referrer - what if it's not passed by the client?

Tags: php, http-referer

I want to remember the referrer, and send the user back to their original site after they submit a form on my site.

My problem arises because the HTTP_REFERRER is not always passed... what are some typical solutions people do to get around this?  Is there any other method besides using $_SERVER to grab this information?

**As an update...**

The site is not mine where they would be coming from....

Answer (score 1):

If I'm honest, most people who choose not to send out this information should be used to this sort of behaviour, I've never understood why anyone would care so much about not sending it so maybe if someone could enlighten me? I assume privacy enthusiasts or something... ?

With that said, what I would do is if a referrer is found then redirect automatically, or store the page they came from in a session and redirect to that link (that's if they came from a page within your site so you could grab it)... other wise you could display a link with the following:

```
<a href="javascript:history.go(-1)">Return</a>
```

But then again, I don't know the full details on your situation.

Answer (score 0):

It depends if you control the server that sets the http_refferer or not.  You can't count on that information being there, so you have to control some of the users path.  For example you could pass a get variable if you know the link that they will be coming from.  There is a reason why you have to do major workaround to get this working.  Because you can't trust information coming from the client.

Comment: Ah yes, I didn't consider the situation where the "other site" might be under the OP's control. In that case, you might also use cookies to store the info before redirecting to the form... but of course that's not trustable either.

Answer (score 0):

You can't rely on HTTP_REFERRER to be set. (Or to be accurate.) The simple (and only) solution is to design your app to gracefully handle the situation. E.g., if you can't detect where they came from, send them to some generic thank you page.

Answer (score 0):

There's no guarantee that the client will send you the referrer (and it's [HTTP_REFERER](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php), by the way, not HTTP_REFERRER).  Some clients will hide it for privacy reasons, and presumably obscure other ways that you might find it as well.  So you should have a default landing page after the form is submitted, for cases when it's not included in the request.

Answer (score 0):

You can never expect the client to send the `HTTP_REFERRER`.

You could  append the current URL to your form action as a `GET` parameter.
Another solution could be cookie/session based.

Some frameworks implement this as a feature called "flash scope" (for a different purpose, but you need something like this).

Comment: If you want to redirect back to a foreign page then HTTP_REFFERRER is your only chance.